# Why won't this heading center?

Tags: html, css

I have a sidebar with the a title in it and I want to center the title in the middle of the sidebar in such a way that the first letter of each word in the title is aligned vertically.

```css
#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #353f4d, #3f4957);
}

#title-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2980b9;
}

.title-text {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: Raleway;
  color: #f2f1f1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <div id="title-div">
      <h1 class="title-text">The<br>Title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body
```

[image: CLICK HERE for the image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display: flex; justify-content: center` for `#title-div` fixes the issue.

If you are new to flexbox I recommend [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

#### Snippet

```css
#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #353f4d, #3f4957);
}

#title-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2980b9;
}

.title-text {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: Raleway;
  color: #f2f1f1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <div id="title-div">
      <h1 class="title-text">The<br>Title</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: But the first letter of each word is not aligned. This is not a valid solution.

Comment: @IvanIvic : I edited my answer, please let me know if it's OK for you.